# Back Up / Share Core Data Store

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data

I'm working on an iPhone app, and in the course of development I have creating what ends up being a really good set of test data on the actual iPhone that I'm using to debug the app.

What is the easiest way to: (1) copy the sqlite store off of the phone and (2) turn that sqlite store into something that can generate test fixtures for my unit tests?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download your app data onto your computer using Xcode's Organizer.

1. Launch Xcode
2. List item
3. Connect your handset
4. In Xcode, go to Window > Organizer
5. Select your device, under "Devices"
6. In the window to the Right, find "Applications" window
7. Find your app and tap on the arrow
   next to the name to expand the list
8. An item should appear underneath the
   app name, titled "Application Data"
9. Click the arrow pointing down,
   located at the far right side of the
   window
10. Save the folder anywhere onto
         your drive

Now you will be able to find your sqlite in the "Documents" folder inside that folder you just saved.